# Applying function over certain values in vector (R)

Tags: r, vector

I would like to know if there is some elegant solution to this problem:

Let's say I have a vector of values

`a <- c(1,2,3,3.1,3.2,5,6,7,7.1,7.2,9)`

and I want to apply some function (e.g. mean) only to values fulfilling certain condition, which in this case is to have the difference between values smaller than  *0.5* .

So the values that should be averaged are `(3,3.1,3.2)` and `(7,7.1,7.2)` and the function should return vector

`b <- c(1,2,3.1,5,6,7.1,9)`

Edit: One approach I've tried (not sure if right) is to binarize the vector `a` (1 meaning the difference between values is <0.5; 0 meaning the diff is >0.5), so I got vector

`bin <– c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0)`

but I don't know how to apply mean to the separate groups of ones. So the main problem for me is to distinguish the groups of needed values and apply the mean to them separately. Any ideas?

I am new here so if anything is unclear, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should provide some attempts that you tried so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't qualify as elegant, but I think that it works in the case you provide. I use `rle` (base R) to identify runs where diffs are less than 0.5.

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 5, 6, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 9) 
crit <- diff(a) < 0.5
crit <- c(head(crit, 1), crit) | c(crit, tail(crit, 1))
run <- rle(crit)
aa <- split(a, rep(seq(length(run$lengths)), times=run$lengths))
myFun <- function(crit, val) {
    if (crit) {
        mean(val)
    }
    else {
        val
    }
}
unlist(mapply(FUN=myFun, crit=run$values, val=aa, USE.NAMES=FALSE))
```

Yields:

```
> unlist(mapply(FUN=myFun, crit=run$values, val=aa, USE.NAMES=FALSE))
[1] 1.0 2.0 3.1 5.0 6.0 7.1 9.0
```

Maybe someone can build a cleaner solution from this.

---

Update: OP points out that this fails on a sequence like {3, 3.1, 3.2, 7, 7.1, 7.2} because the code above lumps this into one run and averages across the whole sequence. Here's a more robust solution.

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 10)

run <- unclass(rle(diff(a) < 0.5))
len <- run$lengths
val <- run$values
pos <- seq_along(len)
last <- pos == max(pos)
len <- len + val - c(0, head(val, -1)) + (last * !val)
prevLen <- c(0, head(cumsum(len), -1))
myFun <- function(l, v, pl, x) {
    if (l == 0) {
        NULL
    } else {
        seg <- seq(l) + pl
        if (v == TRUE) {
            mean(x[seg])
        } else {
            x[seg]
        }
    }
}
unlist(mapply(FUN=myFun, l=len, v=val, pl=prevLen, MoreArgs=list(x=a)))
```

Now whenever it comes across a small difference run (i.e., `val == TRUE`) it adds more one to the length of that small difference run (i.e., `len + val`), but that additional element comes from the next run, but it can't steal from the last run if it's not a small difference run (i.e., `last * !val`).

Comment: +1 I like your `crit <- c(head(crit, 1), crit) | c(crit, tail(crit, 1))`. It is a lot of cleaner than my `d <- diff(a); d <- c(d[1], d); rd <- abs(diff(rev(a))); rd <- c(rd[1], rd); dc <- d < thr | rd < thr`.

Comment: It is effective and elegant enough for me at the moment. I like the rle function which I wasn't aware of before. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have one additional question though. How would you divide the values into groups in a vector `c(2,2.1,2.2,3,3.1,3.2)`? There are two groups of numbers which fulfill the condition so the result should be `c(2.1,3.1)`. However I am unable to distinguish between the groups using your solution, possibly because it is based on changes between TRUE and FALSE values and since there are only TRUE values I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: @qeeZz -- Sorry! Good point. I hadn't considered that case. I'll add a more general (even less elegant) solution.

Comment: @qeeZz -- Also, this is a little sloppy now, but you could wrap the whole thing in an `outerFun()` and have `a` as the only input.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I overcomplicated the problem:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,3.1,3.2,5,6,7,7.1,7.2,9)
thr <- 0.5

## create a correct binary vector
d <- diff(a)
d <- c(d[1], d)
rd <- abs(diff(rev(a)))
rd <- c(rd[1], rd)

dc <- d < thr | rd < thr
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

## use rle to count continous values
r <- rle(dc)
r
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:5] 2 3 2 3 1
#   values : logi [1:5] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE

## create grouping vector
groups <- double(length(a))

groups[!dc] <- seq(sum(!dc))
groups[dc] <- sum(!dc)+rep(seq(sum(r$values)), r$lengths[r$values])
groups
#  [1] 1 2 6 6 6 3 4 7 7 7 5

## create mean for each group
m <- tapply(a, groups, FUN=mean)
m
#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
# 1.0 2.0 5.0 6.0 9.0 3.1 7.1

## recreate origin order
m[order(unique(groups))] <- m
m
#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
# 1.0 2.0 3.1 5.0 6.0 7.1 9.0
```

Comment: Richards' solution is cleaner but yours is easier to understand for beginners like me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility based on `ave`

```
# find id on which mean should be calculated
id1 <- which(diff(a) < 0.5)
id2 <- sort(union(id1, id1 + 1))
id2
# [1]  3  4  5  8  9 10

# group the id
grp <- cumsum(c(1, diff(id2)) - 1)
grp
# [1] 0 0 0 2 2 2

# calulate mean per group and insert into original vector
a[id2] <- ave(a[id2], grp)
a
# [1] 1.0 2.0 3.1 3.1 3.1 5.0 6.0 7.1 7.1 7.1 9.0

# remove duplicated means, i.e. remove index of duplicated values of grp
a[-id2[as.logical(ave(grp, grp, FUN = function(x) duplicated(x)))]]
# [1] 1.0 2.0 3.1 5.0 6.0 7.1 9.0
```

Comment: I especially appreciate the way you grouped the id with cumsum. Thank you Henrik.